# How to run .sas files in cmd where the Sas program is v8 and not 9.4

Tags: sas

so i have seen many commands that are having 9.4/Sas.exe i have 8/SasGuide.exe

im trying to execute this commands

```
"/sas/940/SASFoundation/8/SasGuide.exe" -SYSIN "/projects/program1.sas" -log "/projects/program1.log"
```

but it is opening the sas tool

i want to run the file not to open the file in sas tool

Comment: SAS Enterprise Guide is an editor. It can not run SAS on its own. You should still call the sas.exe file

Comment: i dont have any sas.exe execuatble in 'Program Files/SASHome/SASEnterpriseGuide/8/'

Comment: neither in the entire 'SASHome' folder

Comment: Enterprise Guide is a front end tool to submit code to SAS.  If you have SAS on your machine it will be in a different place.  But most EG users connect to SAS on a server.  There are ways in EG to schedule a project flow, perhaps that is what you need.

Comment: Check if you actually have SAS installed on your machine.  If not copy the program to the machine where SAS is installed and you can run it from the command line on that machine.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/05/03/using-sas-enterprise-guide-to-run-programs-in-batch/